# Chrome keyboard shortcuts while playing local videos?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, video

Google Chrome can play local videos (which is useful, because it's safer than regular video players due to the [sandboxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) it uses).

However, it doesn't have any keyboard bindings except `space` for "pause". Is there any way to configure skip-forward and skip-back keys without installing some extension published by an unfamiliar third party)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There indeed are no other keyboard bindings than the <kbd>Space</kbd> you discovered, and there seems no user exposed way to add different bindings without resorting to browser extensions.

Obviously, there are many video players dedicated to play local content that do have a range of shortcut keys, that eventually can be customized. If you are concerned about security while playing a local file, then you can install such video player as a snap package: applications installed as a snap are also sandboxed. Alternatively, there is a tool `firejail` that allows running applications in a confined environment ("sandbox").

Comment: Everyone constantly complains about `snapd` being forced on them by Ubuntu 20.04, it never even occurred to me it could be useful :-)

Comment: Indeed, the linux community can be quite conservative. Flatpak is another possibility, but snap is default on Ubuntu